# Feature Class to Shapefile with definitions not values

Tags: shapefile, export, file-geodatabase, fields-attributes, domains

I have a point feature class in an SQL Server Geodatabase that we use for day-to-day analysis. Occasionally we receive request for copies of our data from the public and send them shapefiles. If I export to a shapefile directly the coded values are what is written. I want to find a way to produce the shapefile with the textual description of the coded values in the coded value domain in the geodatabase.

> Shapefile:
>   class = 00053
>
> Attribute Table:
>   class = Gravel Street

[image: Screenshot of Database Properties with coded values.]

It looks like [ESRI's Production Mapping Extension](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/production-mapping/converting-a-geodatabase-to-shapefiles.htm) has a tool that could do the trick but want to avoid purchasing an extension if possible.

How can I do this?

Comment: The simplest means would be to use lookup tables to map codes to text, and a view to expose the text instead of the codes, then export from the view.  But be careful -- dBase has a number of restrictions that make it unsuitable for export, including column name width, datetime support, string field width limitation, numeric null support, and a 4000 byte table width limitation. Any of these could impact your export process.

Comment: You could use this: http://desktop.arcgis.com/de/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/domain-to-table.htm, then join the two tables and export the layer to a shapefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution that worked for me and though I would share it.

1. Feature Class to Shapefile tool in ArcMap
2. Set input and output of files
3. Edit the **Environments...**
4. Check the box next to **Transfer field domain descriptions**

[image]

This will export the data and write the description as values instead of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution, as provided by @dpw4050, using a source featureclass that had both subtypes and domains, but it did not work. Instead I used the Feature class to Feature class geoprocessing tool (not the Feature Class to Shapefile tool) to create a shapefile, and modified the Environment Settings as described by @dpw4050 , and it worked.